# Testing authenticate methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm currently trying to learn unit tests and I have created project in ASP.NET Core, so I can learn testing on real example. I want to test happy path for authenticate method in API Controller, so it will return OkObjectResult.

What I have so far.

Controller method i'd like to test

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("authenticate")]
        public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]User userParam)
        {
            var user = _userService.Authenticate(userParam.Nickname, 
            userParam.Password).Result;

            if(user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest(
                  new { message = "Username or password is incorrect " }
                );
            }

            return Ok(user);
        }
```

Authenticate method in class that implements IUserService:

```
public async Task<User> Authenticate(string nickname, string password)
        {
            var user = _repository.User.GetAllUsersAsync().Result.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Nickname == nickname && u.Password == password);

            if(user == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
            var tokenDescription = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserId.ToString())
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescription);
            user.Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

            try
            {
                await _repository.User.UpdateUserAsync(user);

                user.Password = null;

                return user;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return user;
            }

        }
```

And my unit test:

```
        [Fact]
        public void Authenticate_WhenCalled_ReturnsOk()
        {
            //Arrange
            var mockService = new Mock<IUserService>();
            var user = new User()
            {
                UserId = 4,
                IsAdmin = true,
                Token = "12983912803981",
                IsLogged = true,
                MessagesSent = null,
                MessagesReceived = null,
                Nickname = "test3",
                Password = "Str0ngP@ssword123",
                UserChannels = null
            };

            var controller = new UsersController(_repository, _logger, mockService.Object);

            //Act
            var result = controller.Authenticate(user);

            //Assert
            var okResult = result.Should().BeOfType<OkObjectResult>();
        }
```

However, unit tests is returning BadRequest, not OkObjectResult as intended.
That means probably that user is actually null and it's throwing a BadRequest. Should I mock Repository instead of IUserService?

Comment: You should setup method Authenticate of your mock of _userService

Comment: This isn't related to your question, but your code seems to imply that your application is storing passwords in plaintext. Please, please, please don't _ever_ do that in a real-life application. You don't want to get [written up by Troy Hunt](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you are pretty good and doing everything perfectly (too few developers actually using AAA, which is very sad) but do remember that Mock by default returns **default(T)** value. So your Authenticate method is mocked and return **default(User)** which is **null**.
Just make it return your stub user:

```
 var mockService = new Mock<IUserService>();
 var user = new User()
        {
            UserId = 4,
            IsAdmin = true,
            Token = "12983912803981",
            IsLogged = true,
            MessagesSent = null,
            MessagesReceived = null,
            Nickname = "test3",
            Password = "Str0ngP@ssword123",
            UserChannels = null
        };
 mockService.Setup(x=> x.Authenticate(It.IsAny(), It.IsAny())).Returns(user);
```

Or more *strict* version proposed by @*xander*:

```
 mockService.Setup(x=> x.Authenticate("test3", "Str0ngP@ssword123")).Returns(user);
```

It will also check that you actually using values from passed in User and not just blindly return Ok().

Comment: This could be improved slightly by making the `Setup` more specific: `mockService.Setup(x=> x.Authenticate("test3", "Str0ngP@ssword123")).Returns(user);`. Using real values instead of `It.IsAny()` requires that the _correct_ values are passed to the mock.

Comment: Thak you, I will add your advise into answer.

Comment: Thank you guys. That was actually the case. Works like a charm! :)